# Error trying to import projects from TFS via Eclipse and Git

Tags: eclipse, tfs, team-explorer-everywhere

I'm the admin of a VDI environment at my company and we just moved to some new desktops.  We have a team of developers that use Eclipse IDE for coding and use TFS as a repo.  They showed me how they import projects into Eclipse using the Team Explore Anywhere plugin and Git.  This works for all but one of them.  When I attempt to do the same thing, I have the same problem as the 1 person who doesn't work.

Users are not much help, saying it just worked for them and since I have little knowledge in this arena, here I am.  When I attempt to import via "Projects from Git on Team Services or Team Foundation Server" option, it allows me to enter in a server and creds, but when I click Next it immediately bombs out.  Error log below:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.eclipse.egit.core.RepositoryUtil org.eclipse.egit.core.Activator.getRepositoryUtil()'
    at com.microsoft.tfs.client.eclipse.ui.egit.importwizard.CrossCollectionRepositorySelectControl.getDefaultRootFolderPreference(CrossCollectionRepositorySelectControl.java:245)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.client.eclipse.ui.egit.importwizard.CrossCollectionRepositorySelectControl.getDefaultGitRootFolder(CrossCollectionRepositorySelectControl.java:211)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.client.eclipse.ui.egit.importwizard.CrossCollectionRepositorySelectControl.<init>(CrossCollectionRepositorySelectControl.java:120)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.client.eclipse.ui.egit.importwizard.WizardCrossCollectionRepoSelectionPage.createControls(WizardCrossCollectionRepoSelectionPage.java:77)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.wizard.common.WizardCrossCollectionSelectionPage.doCreateControl(WizardCrossCollectionSelectionPage.java:101)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.framework.wizard.ExtendedWizardPage.createControl(ExtendedWizardPage.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.updateForPage(WizardDialog.java:1240)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.lambda$3(WizardDialog.java:1223)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showPage(WizardDialog.java:1223)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(WizardDialog.java:918)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.lambda$0(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4256)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4054)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3642)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$Import.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:97)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4256)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4054)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3642)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.log.EventDetailsDialog.open(EventDetailsDialog.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.log.EventDetailsDialogAction.run(EventDetailsDialogAction.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.log.LogView.lambda$2(LogView.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$1.run(StructuredViewer.java:780)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireDoubleClick(StructuredViewer.java:777)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.handleDoubleSelect(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1542)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetDefaultSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1211)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireDefaultSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4256)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4054)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3642)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:643)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)

Session Data:
eclipse.buildId=4.26.0.20221201-1200
java.version=17.0.4.1
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -data C:\Users\%username%\eclipse-workspace_new_1 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
```

TFS plugin version: 14.135.0.202010141427

Any help is appreciated and please don't assume I have any idea what I'm doing as you would be incorrect in that assumption.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: The [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/issues/345) has been **fixed in [14.138.0](https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases/tag/14.138.0)**.

<del>The TFS plugin uses a method of EGit that does not exist anymore in EGit 5.12 and highery (it has been [removed in this commit](https://git.eclipse.org/c/egit/egit.git/commit/org.eclipse.egit.core/src/org/eclipse/egit/core/Activator.java?id=86708b62d5e4b1d707c4384b0267b60b6d8549a5)).
It's a **known issue of the TFS plugin**, see [TFS plugin issue #353](https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/issues/353).</del>

<del>The fix seems to be easy (see [my comment](https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/issues/353#issuecomment-1513901828)), but unfortunately the [**TFS plugin is no longer maintained**](https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere):</del>

> <del>This project is no longer maintained. To make changes, you may fork
> this repository and build your own version of Team Explorer Everywhere
> using instructions below.</del>

<del>So as long there is no fork that fixes that, **downgrading JGit/EGit to 5.11 or using Eclipse 2021-03** which contains EGit 5.11 seems to be the only **workaround** to make this feature work.</del>